# HTMP/PHP opening remote text document in browser not working Apache( IIS)

Tags: php, html, web, intranet

I have had a basic intranet working fine for a few years running on an IIS server. Our ERP server drops automated reports into a shared (read only) location the users can access on the LAN. 10.0.1.111

To make things simpler, i created a web page which links to named documents with better titles etc in an alphabetical list.

These opened and displayed in a basic webpage (which was all that was wanted) using

```
  <a href="file://10.0.1.111/PRT/01PRINT105" target=_blank>Purchase Report</a><BR>
```

Everything works fine and still does, from the old server.

I then copied the Intranet to an Apache server running on a `synology NAS` drive and nothing works.

Any help recommendations gratefully received. No error messages displayed, just a page that doesn't do anything.*

*The initial page with links show, the hyperlinks don't do anything

PHP or HTML

Comment: The `file:` protocol in there is peculiar - I'd remove that for starters so that you have a proper uri. Also - as this is hosted on a private network there would seem no need to mask the last octet of the ip?!

Comment: "and nothing works", "No error messages displayed, just a page that doesn't do anything.", are you taking about the page with the alphabetical list of links or what happens when you click on one of those links? You could be more specific. Do you get the links, or not?

Comment: Thank you to the above, question edited

Comment: @Professor Abronsius thank you, emoving the file: worked. Looking at it now, I can't see why it was ever there!